# Extract max datum

Tags: sql, teradata

I have two tables: "su" and "wb". 
Left join is made between them on attributes "su.a" and "wb.b".
The table "wb" also contains "l_datum" field.
Desired output: make left join between tables but take only those rows from the "wb" table in the join with the maximum value of "wb.l_datum" field.
DB flavor: Teradata
Can you please help me?

Comment: basically every suggestion I got here. I also always end up retrieving the maximum value of L_Datum column in the entire table. But I can not find the max value of the L_Datum column for a particular value of wb.b i.e. su.a. That is the reason I posted this question

Comment: @Adam that's what a `group by` does...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about teradata, but in regular sql you would do:

```
select su.*, wb.*
from su
join wb on su.a = wb.b
join (
   select wb.b as b, max(wb.l_datum)
   from wb
   group by wb.b
) t on wb.b = t.b
```

Comment: the joins between su and wb are very complicated - therefore I am looking solution without additional joins

Comment: @Adam you have to do two things (i) find the rows that include the maximum l_datum for each wb.b and (ii) limit the original select to only those rows in wb.  That is close to the textbook definition of a join (with a group by sub-select). If your query is too complex you should create views that abstract away some of the complexity.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a
from su 
left join wb
on (su.a = wb.b)
where wb.l_datum = (select max(l_datum) from wb)
```

Comment: What's the point of a left join if you're going to filter out all the rows where no record from wb is found?

Comment: ok i know...  but he said:  Left join is made between them on attributes "su.a" and "wb.b"

Comment: "select max(l_datum) from wb" will as I understand return the most recent date value from the whole table. I need it only for a particular value of wb.b. So - wb.b attribute has more than one value of "wb.L_datum". I want only the recent one - wb.b with the recent value of wb.L_datum

Answer (score 0):

In general, what i can think of is:

```
SELECT col1, col2...
FROM su
LEFT OUTER JOIN wb
ON
su.a = wb.b
WHERE
wb.l_datum = (SELECT max(l_datum) FROM wb)
```

But I think, you need multiple max datum depending upon groups.
In that case, use GROUP BY

Comment: "select max(l_datum) from wb" will as I understand return the most recent date value from the whole table. I need it only for a particular value of wb.b. So - wb.b attribute has more than one value of "wb.L_datum". I want only the recent one - wb.b with the recent value of wb.L_datum

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from wb w left join su s
on w.b=s.a
where w.l_datum=(select max(l_datum) from wb );
```

Comment: there are more than one values for l_datum. So the table "su" has more than one attribute. with su.a I join in the table wb.b. I need to join with the particular su.a attribute and connect only with the wb.b which has the most recent L_datum value

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that you still get `su` records for which no corresponding `wb` record is found, you can filter the `wb` table before joining. The exact accepted syntax varies slightly per database, but it would be something like this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM su
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM wb
    WHERE wb.l_datum = (
        SELECT MAX(wb_maxdatum.l_datum)
        FROM wb AS wb_maxdatum)
) AS wb_filtered
ON wb_filtered.b = su.a
```

You can also try

```
    WHERE wb.l_datum = (
        SELECT MAX(wb_maxdatum.l_datum)
        FROM wb AS wb_maxdatum
        WHERE wb_maxdatum.b = wb.b)
```

to take the maximum date per `b`, instead of over all rows.

Comment: but I believe this will only give me the maximum value of the L_Datum column for the whole table, and not the maximum value of L_Datum for the partular value of su.a=wb.b. What do you think?

Comment: @Adam Yes, that's why I had already included the "You can also try" part, which does not get the maximum of the whole table :)

Comment: I believe it stills retrieves the max L_Datum value from the entire table. There is nothing to connect the particular value from the su.a to the subset of L_Datum values

Comment: @Adam `wb.b` is equal to `su.a`, so taking the maximum per `wb.b` is the same thing as taking the maximum per `su.a`.

Answer (score 0):

What if you replace the `LEFT JOIN` with a derived table using a Window Aggregate Function and `QUALIFY` clause to return the `MAX` value of `l_datum` for each value of `b`

```
select su.*, wb.*
  from su
  left join 
       (
        select *
          from wb
        qualify l_datum = max(l_datum) over(partition by wb.b)
       ) t on wb.b = t.b
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking to not use additional join's ... have you considered leveraging volatile tables to break the processing into steps?

```
-- get  max wb table records 
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE vt_01_wb
AS
(
SEL t1.*
FROM wb t1
LEFT JOIN (SEL b, MAX(l_datum) max_l_datum FROM  wb GROUP BY 1) t2
WHERE t1.l_datum = t2.max_l_datum
) 
WITH DATA PRIMARY INDEX(b) 
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

CREATE VOLATILE TABLE vt_02
AS
(
SEL su.*, wb.*
FROM su
-- volatile table already contians max l_datum
LEFT JOIN vt_01_wb wb ON su.a = wb.b
) WITH DATA 
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

SEL * FROM vt_02
```